# Where can I find Field History Tracking metadata for Activity object?

Tags: deployment, custom-field, metadata, activity, sourcecontrol

I have set some fields for field history tracking on Task object. The standard field metadata files have `<trackHistory>true</trackHistory>`.

The custom field for Task was created in the Activity object. I can have this Activity custom field turned on for field history tracking and it works fine. However, the metadata of this field in Activity does not have anything defined for field history tracking.

Does anyone know where can I get the metadata that defines it? I need to push it to my source control and deploy to other orgs. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually all the attributes of fields can be retrieved from this object : `FieldDefinition`

Try this query: `select FIELDS(ALL) from FieldDefinition where LastModifiedDate = today and EntityDefinitionId = 'Task' limit 100`

`IsFieldHistoryTracked` is what you are looking for.

You have to provide `EntityDefinitionId` or `DurabilityId`  in the filters.